# How to make a Processing Sketch with external libraries and files work on a website?

Tags: java, javascript, html, export, processing

So I have made a game using Processing and have used 2 java libraries (minim for sound and java.util.map for a hashmap), as well as having many external image and sound files which the game uses. I want to put the game on my website, in a way that you can play it without downloading it. I have not been able to find a way of ding this so I thought I'd ask here.

Comment: If you're using Java libraries, you will not be able to use the JavaScript mode, you'll have to export it as a Java Applet to be run in the browser.

Comment: @kevinsa5 and what if the server is a Java server, would it run then?

Comment: @fartagaintuxedo wow, a comment from 2014!  The server is irrelevant, it only matters what is running in the user's browser.  Processing in JS mode cannot use Java libraries, and vice versa.  They are completely separate languages and execution environments.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you can't.

You *can* deploy basic Processing sketches using [Processing.js](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/processing-js), but that won't work if your sketch contains Java libraries.

(Side note: you don't need to import `java.util.HashMap` to use it in a Processing sketch. Just use [`HashMap`](https://processing.org/reference/HashMap.html) directly. That would actually work with Processing.js.)

If you use Java libraries, then your only option is to deploy as an application and have users download your program.

The other option is to get rid of the Java libraries and use JavaScript libraries instead. You can call JavaScript code from Processing.js code. See [here](http://processingjs.org/articles/jsQuickStart.html#combineprocessingandjavascript) for more info.

Shameless self-promotion: I wrote a guide on the different versions of Processing and how you can deploy them, available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/p5js/which-processing).