# Would a processing sketch that uses java libraries work on a java server website?

Tags: java, processing, web-hosting

I know this question is very basic, but it was already asked and it doesn't have a very complete answer, actually it's just a comment:

[How to make a Processing Sketch with external libraries and files work on a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219229/how-to-make-a-processing-sketch-with-external-libraries-and-files-work-on-a-webs)

So, i know this doesn't work on PHP servers, but what if I have a java hosting? Would it work then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please understand the difference between something running on a server and something running on a client. The question you linked to isn't asking about a server at all. It's asking about running a Processing sketch in a browser, not on a server.

What kind of server you're using doesn't matter if you're just trying to run stuff in the browser. You just need a basic file server, and there are many free options. I personally like [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/).

You'll need to use [Processing.js](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/processing-js) or [P5.js](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/p5js) to deploy your Processing sketch to a webpage. I wrote a guide on the differences between these Processing versions [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/p5js/which-processing).

If you are really asking about how to run Processing on a server and not in a browser, then see this page: https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Running-without-a-Display

Comment: That's a nice guide, thank you. I have loads of visualizations that use java comparators, i find these really hard to implement in p5.js... it's a shame because i really would like to adapt them to javascript - perhaps i should give it a go? Or would it be easier to run them on a headless processing in a java server and then figure out a way to stream all the frames one by one to the client?

Comment: @fartagaintuxedo That's going to depend more on you than on anything else. Which do you think is easier? Personally I think P5.js is easier, but it depends on your background and how you want your program to behave. Honestly the best thing you can do is try both out with a simple example and see which approach you like best.